# Cannot open Instagram Followers page with Python

Tags: python, selenium

I need to open Instagram Followers Page with Python. I have already tried several ways to do it, but have no results... Can someone help me, please?
First I tried to do it this way:

```
# Go to the Group
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/biblio_com/')
time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="/biblio_com/followers/"]').click()
```

But it gives an error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <a class=" _81NM2" href="/biblio_com/followers/"> could not be scrolled into view
```

Then I tried the following:

```
# WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[@href="/biblio_com/followers/"]'))).click()
```

But it gives the same error ... (((
Another way I was trying to solve this problem was:

```
followers_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="/biblio_com/followers/"]')
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(followers_link).click(followers_link).perform()
```

It gives no error. But it also gives no result ...
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="/biblio_com/followers/"]').click()
```

I tried with chromedriver and for me it is working. What browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox... Let me try with ChromeDriver also... Which of the solutions worked for you?

Comment: I've changed it to Chrome. And now it's working )

Comment: updated the answer with working solution.